# Room database generic DAO class error: name clash: insert(List<Entity>) and insert(List<? extends Entity>) have the same erasure

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to implement UPSERT (update or insert) method myself because @UPSERT annotation is only available in version 2.5.0-beta01 and I want to wait for a stable release. Here is what I did:
I write a `BaseDao<T>` and other DAO classes which extend the `BaseDao`, so then I don't have to manually write basic functions for every DAO class

```
@Dao
abstract class BaseDao<T> {
    
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(obj: T): Long

    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(obj: List<T>): List<Long>

    @Update(onConflict = REPLACE)
    abstract fun update(obj: T)

    @Update(onConflict = REPLACE)
    abstract fun update(obj: List<T>)

    @Transaction
    open fun insertOrUpdate(obj: T) {
        val id = insert(obj)
        if (id == -1L) update(obj)
    }

    @Transaction
    open fun insertOrUpdate(obj: List<T>) {
        val insertResult = insert(obj)
        val rowsToUpdate = insertResult.mapIndexedNotNull { index, rowId ->
            if (rowId == -1L) null else obj[index]
        }

        if (rowsToUpdate.isNotEmpty()) update(rowsToUpdate)
    }
}
```

And child DAO class:

```
@Dao
abstract class MyDao : BaseDao<MyEntity> {
  
    @Insert(entity = MyEntity::class)
    abstract override fun insert(obj: MyEntity): Long

    @Insert(entity = MyEntity::class)
    abstract override fun insert(obj: List<MyEntity>): List<Long>

    @Update(entity = MyEntity::class)
    abstract override fun update(obj: MyEntity)

    @Update(entity = MyEntity::class)
    abstract override fun update(obj: List<MyEntity>)
}
```

But when building the app it returns errors:

```
MyDao_Impl.java:398: error: name clash: insert(List<? extends MyEntity>) in MyEntity_Impl and insert(List<MyEntity>) in MyDao have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
MyDao_Impl.java:461: error: name clash: update(List<? extends MyEntity>) in MyEntity_Impl and update(List<MyEntity>) in MyDao have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

In my understanding Room doesn't understand that MyDao class is overriding the methods of BaseDao and it tries to implement the abstract functions of both MyDao and BaseDao. I just don't understand why this issue happens to `insert(obj: List<MyEntity>)` but `insert(obj: MyEntity)`
If I remove all annotations in BaseDao and make it just a normal abstract class then I have to override `insertOrUpdate()` function every time. This goes against the goal of BaseDao.
Do you have any ideas or guides to help me achieve that approach?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `onConflict` options to the annotations?

Comment: @TheLibrarian    yes, I also have tried that. The result is the same. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What version of Room are you using? Are you using Kapt or KSP already? What does the entity look like? (I tried the code and it works fine so far)